# Oracle reports buider installation

Tags: oracle11g, installation, oraclereports

I want install Oracle 11g report builder, but not know what I'm must downlaod because i ;m download `Oracle Database 11g Release 2` and I can't found there Report builder maybe I must download something else ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/reports/downloads/index.html) is 11g Bulder and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24269_01/doc.11120/e23960/install.htm) you can find documentation.